# When trying to connect to an external postgres database using pgAdmin, I get an error

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, azure-vm, pgadmin-4

I get the following error when trying to connect:

> "FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off"

The db is installed on an Ubuntu machine in Azure. I have allowed inbound connections on port 5432, so there should be no issue there however.

I have edited and added the following lines to the `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf` file on the server:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
hostssl all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

even when I tried to change the mode to trust, I couldn't get a connection established.

I also edited the listen addresses to be: `"listen_addresses = '*'"` in `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf`.

I have ran the command `service postgresql restart` after making each of the changes.

Comment: Can you connect it from the command line? `psql --host=your.azure.ip --port=5432 --user=yourUserName`? I suspect a pgadmin misconfiguration is more likely.

Comment: Same error comes up. I also added local all all md5 before testing this. When i change user on the machine to by "su postgres" and just write psql it works

Comment: Then my second most likely reason is that the DB is using actually a different `pg_hba.conf`, not the one you are editing.

Comment: The changes you've wrote should make it working. It is a highly misterious problem for me. What is in /var/log/postgresql ?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the is the bold part, the `host ""`:

> "FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for **host ""**, user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off"

The database, from which you get the error, see a local connection, and not a networked one.

How can it happen, it depends on your system configuration, what you didn't share here.